# Should I assign class fields via property setter or not in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

What is the correct way of doing this? The property setter might contain more code than just the acctual assignment. Lets say I have the following code:

```
class Person
{
    private String name;

    public Person(String name)
    {
        this.name = Name
    }

    public String Name
    {
        get;
        set {
            if(String.Empty.Equals(value)) return;
            this.name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Is the above code wrong since I am not assign via the property?

Comment: `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`.

Comment: @SLaks Technically not *entirely* equivalent, but very likely what was actually intended :-)

Comment: Yes, that's wrong. If the caller isn't allowed to set the value to null or empty, throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value")` rather than silently doing nothing.

Comment: Don't forget to return Person.name from the getter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Unless you've got a good reason to do otherwise, you should use the property `Name` instead of the field `name`, even in the same class, to ensure that the logic in your `get`/`set` methods is always used.
2. Since you explicitly specify a `set` implementation, you must also explicitly specify a `get` implementation for your example to compile.
3. In most cases, you should use [`String.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx), not other approaches like your `String.Empty.Equals(value)` code.
4. Properties should usually behave in unsurprising ways. After you run `person.Name = "";`, you'd expect the `Name` property to be `""`, not what it was before.  If setting a null or empty name is not valid, you should throw an exception when you are passed such a value.

   ```
   class Person
   {
       private String name;

       public Person(String name)
       {
           this.Name = name;
       }

       public String Name
       {
           get {
               return this.name;
           }
           set {
               if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                   throw new ArgumentException("Name is required", "value");
               this.name = value;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: This is a great answer. It all makes sense.

Comment: Please consider adding: `&& value != this.name`  You will be much happier if you should need to use OnPropertyChange at some point in your life.

Answer (score 1):

In general you should assign via the property setter because setters are there to maintain [class invariants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_invariant). Bypassing the setter means that you must manually maintain these invariants when directly modifying the backing field(s), exposing you to bugs and possibly violating the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

In specific cases where *you have already proven* that bypassing the setter yields important performance benefits, feel free to disregard this rule.

Answer (score 1):

Properties should behave in an unsurprising way. That means that if I do:

```
someObject.SomeProperty = someValue;
```

then after doing so, either the following should be true (assuming that the type of the property allows comparison), or an exception should have been thrown:

```
someObject.SomeProperty == someValue;
```

For your example, if you do not want the caller to set the property to a null or empty string then you should throw an `ArgumentException` if they do so:

```
public String Name
{
    get 
    {
        return this.name; 
    }

    set 
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            throw new ArgumentException("value");

        this.name = value;
    }
}
```

I would not like to see this kind of thing:

```
myObject.Name = "Fred";
// ... Lots of code
myObject.Name = "";
string test = myObject.Name;
// Now test == "Fred" wtf?
```

Comment: Should just be an ArgumentException, really.

Comment: @It'sNotALie Usually I reserve `ArgumentException` for those cases where more than one argument is involved, e.g. when you want `min < max` kind of thing. Microsoft say that an `ArgumentOutOFRangeException` should be thrown when `The exception that is thrown when the value of an argument is outside the allowable range of values as defined by the invoked method` which I think applies here.

Comment: @It'sNotALie I think this probably falls into the "that's debatable" category. ;) I'll change it to ArgumentException anyway.